# Javascript parse JSON into table html

Tags: javascript, html

I' m trying to display datas from json into a table in html. SO far I have the following.

- I need help to parse the data in dom
- at the moment I can't display the datas properly. Specially the

  "1day": {
  "movement": 0.28,
  "price": null
  }

```js
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
      callback(rawFile.responseText);
    }
  };
  rawFile.send(null);
}

//usage:
readTextFile("popular-feed.json", function(text) {
  var data = JSON.parse(text);
  //console.log(data);

  //SEE HERE

  var obj = JSON.parse(text, function(key, value) {
    console.log(key[1]);
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="code"></div>
<div id="spread"></div>
```

Comment: You already parsed the json with 'data = JSON.parse(text)', you don't have to do it twice later on. Which fields would you like to access?

Comment: @Corrl sure thanks. I would like to access all of them and display on the dom/table

Comment: what `console.log(data);` shows?